# Is there a magic method in Magento that will be called automatically when a user leaves a page?

Tags: php, magento

I have custom cart and checkout process, so the sales_quote_* is not used at all. Just like Magento default cart form, there are 3 submit buttons: Update Cart, Continue Shopping and Checkout. Whilst the Continue Shopping button is easy, I have a problem with Update Cart and Checkout buttons.

If a user clicks Update Cart, then there is no problem because I can capture all the form values into sessions. The problem is when the user directly clicks on Checkout button. That because one form cannot have 2 submit buttons. So, I simply redirect the Checkout button to a controller.

So, if a user directly clicks on Checkout button, I won't be able to capture some of the form values (like User Note, Custom PO, etc). Is there a magic method that will be automatically executed when someone leaves a Magento page (something like __contruct()) ? If yes, I want to use this magic method to capture the form values.

Comment: Well, I'm not too familiar with magento, but what about using JS and AJAX for that? you can catch the event when a user leaves the page(onbeforeunload event) and then run a script that will set the data you want into a session using AJAX.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try that. Can I use jQuery?

Comment: I would suggest using jQuery for the AJAX request, it really simplifies it. You can also use it for the onbeforeunload event by using the function `bind` it will look something like: `$(window).bind('beforeunload',function() { // ajax request});`

Answer (score 0):

In JQuery (I see you asked for a solltion in the comments), you can bind on this:

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', ...
```

I have some code here, that I dont remember where came from:
http://jsfiddle.net/Olavxxx/K4NCM/

Answer (score 0):

A solution uses jQuery would be as follows:

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload',function() {
   var var1 = $("#element1").val();//maybe .text() depends on the element type and so on..
   $.post('setSession.php',{var1:var1, var2:var2, var3:var3});
});
```

Ofcourse you can use `$.get()` if you'd like to. You can also use the `$.ajax()`, This is just the basic structure.

Good luck!